# Multiple security configurations for specific endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am wondering if there is a way to provide two separate types of authentication?
 User should log, register, get user data for endpoints `/login`, `/register`, `/user` using basic auth. And when I call `/api` it should only be authenticated with **JWT** token provided in headers.

But when I call  `/api` I get all data without any authentication. When user is logged and call `/user`, API gives JWT to access `/api`.

My code:

Configuration for basic auth:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable();
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/user");
    }
```

Configuration for JWT auth:

```
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class JWTSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .antMatcher("/api/**")
            .addFilterAfter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic().disable();
    }
```

Comment: I followed spring docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity) but I don't know what is wrong with my code,

Comment: You have to disable HTTP session, if you want authenticate with every request.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I wanted basic Authentication for some endpoints and for some other I wanted other authentication methods. like yours. you wanna basic authentication for some of the endpoints (`/login`,`/register`, `/user` ) and JWT authentication for some other(`/api/**`).

I used some tutorials about multiple [entry points in spring security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-entry-points) **but it didn't work.**

### **So here is my solution (It worked)**

Separate **basic authentication** from **JWT authentication** by creating a custom filter.

1. Add a prefix path for the endpoints that should be authenticated using basic authentication. like :
   (`/basic/login`, `/basic/register`,`/basic/user`)
2. Create a new custom filter for `/basic` prefix (for `/basic` requests) and check basic authentication

   ```
   @Component
   public class BasicAuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

       HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

       //Check for the requests that starts with /basic 
       if (httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().startsWith("/basic/")) {

           try {
               //Fetch Credential from authorization header
               String authorization = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
               String base64Credentials = authorization.substring("Basic".length()).trim();
               byte[] credDecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Credentials);
               String credentials = new String(credDecoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
               final String username = credentials.split(":", 2)[0];
               final String password = credentials.split(":", 2)[1];

               //Check the username and password
               if (username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")) {
                   //continue
                   chain.doFilter(request, response);
               } else
                   throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("");
           } catch (Exception e) {
               throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("");
           }

       } else chain.doFilter(request, response);

     }

   }
   ```
3. Write main security configuration just for JWT and permit `/basic` URL

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class JWTSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/basic/**").permitAll().and()
               .csrf().disable()
               .antMatcher("/api/**")
               .addFilterAfter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
               .authorizeRequests()
               .anyRequest().authenticated()
               .and()
               .httpBasic().disable();
   }
   ```